# Checkboxes in LotusScript

Tags: checkbox, lotusscript

I have a field of type checkbox which has many values. Is there a way to check which if a particular values is checked? Just like how we have "checked" method in Javascript, is there a similar method in LotusScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes are just items in a document. To get the "checked" values you just read it from the document.

If your Checkbox- Field is called `MyCheckbox` then this code in a Button in the form would give you an array with all values:

```vb
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim varValues as Variant

Set uidoc = ws.currentDocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document

varValues = doc.GetItemValue( "MyCheckBox" ) 
If not isnull( arraygetindex( varValues, "A" ) ) then
   'do whatever you want if "A" is selected
Else
   'do something else
End If
If not isnull( arraygetindex( varValues, "B" ) ) then
   'do whatever you want if "B" is selected
End If
If not isnull( arraygetindex( varValues, "C" ) ) then
   'do whatever you want if "C" is selected
End If
```

Comment: I take your suggestion, but what if I have to do more work based on which value in the checkbox is selected.

Comment: Suppose in the field "MyCheckBox", I have values like A, B and C. So I need to check if A is selected, if yes then I should executed some conditions and if no, then another condition. Similarly for B and C

Answer (score 2):

There's no `checked` property for a checkbox field in LotusScript API.

All Lotus Notes fields are text fields by its nature. Checkbox fields are text and multivalue fields.

`Multivalue`- means that field can hold several values at once.

If you do not use synonims in a checkbox field, then when you read this field contents, you will get a text-array, with all visible values selected.

I. e, if you have checkbox field with name `myCheckBoxField` with selected values:

- apples
- oranges
- airplanes

then you can get this field value as:

```
....
Dim myCheckBoxFieldValues as Variant

myCheckBoxFieldValues = myDocument.getItemValue("myCheckBoxFieldValues")
```

and `myCheckBoxFieldValues` will be a string array, with values

- apples
- oranges
- airplanes

But, if you have used synonims for your checkbox field, which is strongly recommended if there's a functionality that relates upon this checkbox field values, then the picture is a bit different.

Let say there is the following set of options for your checkbox field (synonims are separated via `|`  symbol):

- apples | 1
- oranges| 2
- plums | 3
- tacos | 4
- airplanes | 5

then, if you have selected options in your document:

- apples
- oranges
- airplanes

and have read this field value as described above, you will get a string array with synonim values, not visible values.

I,e you will get an array with values:

- 1
- 2
- 5

Note that when you will work with values of checkbox fields.

And if you get a string array, with one empty element (index = 0), then your checkbox field does not have any option checked.